# How to diagonalize a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I have given the matrix 
\begin{equation}
    A = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 4 & 2 \\ 4 & 6 \end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
And I have to diagonalize it, but I have no idea from where to start. I need help.

Comment: You could start by finding the matrix' eigenvalues and associated eigenvectors.

Comment: @DavidMitra Once I find them what do I do?

Comment: @user117293: Choose a basis formed of eigenvectors, and apply to $A$ basis change to that basis. Diagonalising a matrix _is_ expressing it on a basis formed of eignevectors (provided one exists).

Comment: I'm kinda lost to be honest, I don't know what is going on exactly. But it seems kinda complex for 2x2 matrix.

Comment: @user117293 do you know what eigenvalues are, and how to find them? In this case It's sufficient to find only one of them, and the other by subtracting from the trace of $
A$

Comment: @Dror I don't know what eigenvalues are, nor how to find them. We never studied that... :/

Comment: @user117293 It is strange you were given this exercise then..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First find its eigenvalues, which are the roots of its characteristic polynomial:
$$
p(x)=x^2-10x+16=(x-2)(x-8).
$$
So the eigenvalues are $2$ and $8$.

Then find non-zero vectors $u$ and $v$ such that
$$
Au=2u, \quad Av=8v.
$$
Then $A=UDU^{-1}$, where $D$ is diagonal with elements of the diagonal $2$ and $8$, and $U$ is the matrix with columns $u$ and $v$.